# Facebook Connect w/o Keyboard on in Full Screen Mode

Tags: facebook, touch, kiosk-mode

We have a requirement to use facebook connect on a touch screen kiosk that's running in windows in Kiosk Mode.  There is not a physical keyboard on the kiosk. Any ideas on how to get a virtual keyboard that can be used to pass credentials to facebook so that we can authenticate users? Facebook does not seem to allow support authenticating users outside of their login page.

Comment: My approach would be to replicate a keyboard. Each of the keyboard buttons would send the corresponding keypress Windows Message to the browser control. However, when the user touches the keyboard button, the browser control loses focus and the sent Windows message wouldn't be handled by a text box within the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution on Windows Form. 
The class SendKeys can simulate keyboard events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.SENDKEYS.SEND);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

The setup is a form with a WebBrowserControl and a bunch of buttons for the keyboard keys. Here's the event handler for a keyboard button.

```
private void buttonKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control _sender = sender as Control;
        if (_sender != null)
        {
            //focus the webBrowser
            bool focusResult = false;
            do
            {
                focusResult = webBrowser1.Focus();
                if (!focusResult)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            } while (!focusResult);

            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.Send("+{TAB}");
            SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
            SendKeys.Send(_sender.Text);
        }
    }
```